# Change text if the value of the variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, if-statement, undefined

I want to have it so that when the variable is undefined the text displays "variable is undefined" but my current code does not do this.

```
if (metar.clouds) {
        document.getElementById('cloud_block').classList.remove("d-none");
        metar.clouds.forEach(cloud => {
          var el = document.createElement('li');
          el.innerHTML = cloud.text + ' at ' + cloud.feet + 'ft AGL. ';
          document.getElementById("cloud_list").appendChild(el);
        });
      }

      if (typeof cloud.feet === "undefined") {
      cloud.feet = "variable is undefined";
    }
```

Comment: You're accessing cloud outside its scope? Plus, how cloud.feet = "variable is undefined"; is supposed to change its text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't be your code like this instead

```
if (metar.clouds) {
    document.getElementById('cloud_block').classList.remove("d-none");
    metar.clouds.forEach(cloud => {
      var el = document.createElement('li');
      if (typeof cloud.feet === "undefined") {
         el.innerHTML = "variable is undefined";
      } else {   
         el.innerHTML = cloud.text + ' at ' + cloud.feet + 'ft AGL. ';   
      }
      document.getElementById("cloud_list").appendChild(el);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I needed!